# How to create modern page in SharePoint online using CSOM Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, modern-pages, modern-team-site

I want to create modern page in a modern site using CSOM PowerShell instead of PNP.
After creating that I need to configure list and Events we part in that.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below csom script to create modern page:

```
$siteUrl="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael"
$ListName="Site Pages"
$UserName="michael"
$Password ="password"
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$item=$list.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile("/sites/michael/SitePages/ModernPage.aspx",[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TemplateFileType]::ClientSidePage).ListItemAllFields
$item["ContentTypeId"] = "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118";
$item["Title"]="ModernPage"
$item["ClientSideApplicationId"] = "b6917cb1-93a0-4b97-a84d-7cf49975d4ec"
$item["PageLayoutType"] = "Article"
$item["PromotedState"] = "0"
$item["CanvasContent1"] = "<div></div>"
$item["BannerImageUrl"] = "/_layouts/15/images/sitepagethumbnail.png"
$item.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting your time, Michael. Can I insert/configure the default webparts like "Events","Announcement" while creating the modern page?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no CSOM API's to add webparts to modern page. You'd better use PNP powershell to add web parts to modern page.